# Gitlab Page Visitor Traffic for Private Repo

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

When we use this `https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/graphs/traffic` url in GitHub, a graph of our repo's visitors will be shown. There is also a table which shows the referring sites.

Does this feature exists for GitLab Page of a private repo? Or is there any workaround to see the visitor counts without the needs of adding any third party visitor counter web plugin?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it doesn't exist yet, as this [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages/issues/189) suggests.